# Apache logging: rotating logs on Win32?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I was noticing my disk space disappearing faster than expected, and finally narrowed it down to a rewrite.log file that was 4 GB in size!

Is there a way to rotate the various Apache logs (rewrite, error, access, etc.) on a Win32 PC so that only the most recent entries are there and I can limit the data size that results? I found the bit about [log rotation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/logs.html#rotation) on Apache's website but it's Unix-centric.

**Edit:** I got rotatelogs.exe to work, and it's great except that it slows the server response down noticably so I rejected the idea of using it.

Comment: Rewrite logs are only usually needed when debugging so why do you still have it enabled in the first place?

Comment: well, that's a good point... maybe you could elaborate as an answer? (there's still the error + access logs though)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mod_log_rotate`. It runs as a server process so it won't spawn multiple instances for each virtual server. See http://www.hexten.net/wiki/index.php/Mod-log-rotate for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Apache indeed can log rewrites. The destination log file is specified by **RewriteLog**.

Disappearing free space could be a sign that you might need to decrease the logging verbosity. If you don't process this rewrite log later (and I assume that you don't, since processing a 4GB log is a time consuming task), you might tell apache to not write it at all. This is more a facility for debugging rewrite rules during development.